# jquery set value with only part of value

Tags: jquery

Would like to set value of select box - but only know second part of comma separated value
e.g if only know value = 2, how do i select the option val b,2?

```
    <select id='aselect'>
           <option value = 'a,1'>
           <option value = 'b,2'>
    </select>
```

know this is odd q - but your help is much appreciated

zim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#aselect option[value$='," + value + "']").prop( "selected", true );
```

Comment: @Vladimirs -- Fixed it for him :)

Comment: Hi- am getting this error

Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #x_NEWstockbody option[value=$=',Hatchback']

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, though currently untested, with plain JavaScript:

```
var option = document.querySelector('option[value$=",2"]');
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
var option = $('option[value$=",2"]');
```

Assuming that you then want to set those values to be the selected `option`:

```
var option = document.querySelector('option[value$=",2"]');
option.selected = true;
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
var option = $('option[value$=",2"]').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: You'll want to include the `,`.  otherwise this would match "c,12" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var partVal = '2';
var fullVal = $('#aselect option[value$="' + partVal + '"]').val();
$('#aselect').val(fullVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use JQuery [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('option[name$="2"]')
```